# Reading a 4 bytes date (big endian) from binary file

Tags: c, date, gcc, compiler-construction, endianness

I have a date encoded (big endian) in 4 bytes that I'm trying to read from a binary file.

I do:

```
char date[4];
long seconds;
s = read(fd, date, sizeof(char) * 4);
seconds = (date[3]<<0) | (date[2]<<8) | (date[1]<<16) | (date[0]<<32);

printf("%s\n", ctime(&seconds));
```

But I get:

```
Thu Jan  1 00:59:27 1970
```

What's wrong with my code ? Thanks.

Comment: Is your system Little Endian?

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` equals 1 by definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(date[0]<<32);
```

looks wrong. `16 + 8` is `24` not `32`.

Comment: If date[3] = -128, doesn't `seconds = (date[3]<<0)` become `0xFFFFFF80`?  Should not `date` be an unsigned array?

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce your code complexity by using `ntohl(3)`:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
/* ... */
uint32_t date;
s = read(fd, &date, sizeof(date));
seconds = ntohl(date);
```

Comment: That's the way to go.